# Unable to run a Java program from shell ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java

I am trying to run a Java program from the bash shell.
The program uses some 3rd party libs (mysql connector , amazon aws)

This is just a standard java program , not running on a J2EE server or anything complicated.

It always complains that it cannot find one of the classes in the third party libs (ClassNotFoundException) (If I remove references to this then it will complain about a different one).

This is confusing since I have checked that the location of the jar files containing the libs is in the classpath. I have also tried putting the libs in the same folder as the .class File I am trying to run to no avail.

I compiled the program using the javac command on the same computer and it had no problems finding the libraries , so I am confused as to why it cannot find them at runtime..

I also tried this from cmd under windows but got the same problem.

The only rational explaination I can find is that it is due to security restrictions in the JVM , in which case it would be good to know how to disable them for this program?

Thanks

Comment: what does your command line look like?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of what Bozho said but for jar files you have to call out the jar file by path AND name, just not the path to them.  From what I gathered from your post you are only adding the path.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you had put the commandline that you are using in the question. It is basically something like this `java -classpath c:/libs/myjar.jar;c:/libs/myjar2.jar;c:/myclasses MyClass` where  MyClass is your "main" java class the -classpath option is the list of areas where you want the runtime to look for dependencies. The .jar are jar files and the folder myclasses is a folder where you may have a .class files or other config information that the program may need.

Comment: I have tried this, it works ok in windows cmd. But now on linux it claims that it cannot find the MyClass

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out for Linux, it's java -classpath "/path/to/jar/myjar.jar:." MyClass